# utils is not defined and Expected undefined to be function

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-node, jasmine2.0, grunt-contrib-jasmine

"I'm trying to cover my default function through to jasmine. But facing issue with dependency files where jasmine is unable to took reference of those dependency. Getting 1 error utils is not defined and 2 error Expected undefined to be function".

"I tried to create mock data for utils is not defined and second i didn't try. But i was able to reproduce second error after comment utils line and that is for x storage."

```
const default = (newu) => {
    newu.isPay = utils.isPayUser(b$.portal.loggedInUserRole);
    xStorage.getItem('Id').then(value => {
      newu.successResponse.bId = value;
      newu.bId = newu.successResponse.bId.replace(/-/g, "");
      newu.bId = newu.bId.slice(0, -10);
    });
  }

describe('default', () => {
  it('default is defined', () => {
    let yesValue = true;
    let utils = {
      isPayUser:(yesValue)=>{}
      } 
    expect(default(ctrl)).toBeFunction();     
  });

});
```

"How i can cover functions with third party dependencies. Do we write some mock data and if yes what would be the way to write it.  Utils and xstorage is a function and coming from dependency files which i already imported in my js file. This method will returns me true “utils.isPayUser(b$.portal.loggedInUserRole);” and xstorage return me get item. Xstorage is a method where we can store a value and whenever or wherever can access to get that value as like as sessionstorage."

Comment: Why are you using the keyword `new` as an object? It is bad practice and pattern. It is a reserved keyword of the language.

Comment: Yes, it is just to post code here. We can change it.

Comment: what is the output when you run this test? Can you share it? Also, `default` function does not return anything, so invoking `default(ctrl)` will always return `undefined`

Comment: Error is utils is not defined. Yes default function wont return anything. I used that to toBeFunction just to cover a function.

Comment: Where is defined `default`? Obviously, it is not in the same test file, right? Is this a `NodeJS` application? Or, it is a frontend application? I'm asking because I see that your function `default` has dependencies on other objects, like `utils`, `xStorage` and `b$`. All that info is needed in order to correctly suggest a solution on how to mock those dependencies.

Comment: Yes right, this application is in node. Utils and xstorage is a function and coming from dependency files which i already imported in my js file. This method will returns me true “utils.isPayUser(b$.portal.loggedInUserRole);” and xstorage return me get item. Xstorage is a method where we can store a value and whenever or wherever can access to get that value as like as sessionstorage.

Comment: Can you show your js file that you referred in your comment: _Utils and xstorage is a function and coming from dependency files which I already imported in my js file._. Just share the relevant part

Comment: with you definition of `default` it will always be `undefined` as you are not returning anything from calling it (it has no return statement)

Comment: second thing `utils` are undefined because they are not defined in global scope you overriding in test case doesnt change anything for interior of `default` function definition you would need to inject `utils` into it like for example this: `const default = (newu, utils) => {`